# How do I make a timer so when a player dies, they have to wait to respawn

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I hope that question is good, I just want to know how if a player dies, that go into spectator mode for a certain amount of time (15 mins here).

I'm using paper 1.17 and can't find any plugin for what I need.
If there's a command block(s) command I can do to make this work that would be nice also.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Run this (in chat):

```
/scoreboard objectives add died deathCount
```

and these in constantly running, chained command blocks (in order too):

```
gamemode spectator @a[scores={died=1}]
scoreboard players add @a[scores={died=1..}] died 1
gamemode survival @a[scores={died=17998}]
kill @a[scores{died=17998}]
scoreboard players set @a[scores{died=18000}] died 0
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me for some reason, can you show an example?

Comment: The problem seems to be that I put the wrong number on the 3rd command (the gamemode survival one), I have edited my answer which should hopefully fix it